# NetworkManager.service VS. systemd-networkd.service VS networking.service

Tags: networking

I am curious why there are (at least) 3 different program for controlling networking on **Debian 5.18.5**. I have `NetworkManager.service`, `systemd-networking.service`, and `networking.service` which are all able to be start with `systemctl`. I can use only `NetworkManager.service` by running `systemctl enable/start NetworkManager.service`. So is there a need for `networking.service` and/or `systemd-networking.service`?